# How to solve this matrix for h and k?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am going through my mathproblems, to check up on what was done during class. The TA had us solve this augmented matrix, but during answering he mixed up the h and k. So my answer is incomplete, and I can't seem to solve it.

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & h & 2 \\ 4 & 8 & k \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & h & 2 \\ 0 & 8-4h & k-8 \end{pmatrix}

I end up in the second matrix. But I am unsure how to get rid of the h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

- Multiply the first row with $8-4h$ and the second row with $h$.
- Subtract the second row from the first.